# Any downside to using fan box as wall sconce box?

Tags: wiring, lighting

I went to Home Depot, Platt and All Phase yesterday and oddly no one has round boxes in stock.

I’m using the round boxes for wall sconces.

I ended up buying some overpriced fiber “fan boxes” which look identical to round boxes (except beefier and with a bracket to carry weight), but the screw orientation is a little different. It’s East-West vs NE-SW on typical round boxes.

Wondering if in general sconce-style fixtures will assume the diagonal screw orientation vs horizontal or if it doesn’t really matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run into this a number of times where the boxes had holes NE and SW instead of N-S and E-W. Sometimes the fixture had a weird hole pattern. You can pick up a universal bracket that will solve your problem, see photo below. There are a few variations of the bracket out there but the results are the same. there have been times when I rimmed the fixture with a bead of caulk against the wall to make sure it didn't twist and also tightened the fixture against the wall pretty tight.

[image]

Comment: yeah - i've used those in ceiling fixtures before (often included) guess they would work with a sconce too. weird that there is no standard to screw orientation.